# Why does $x \in A \implies x \in B$ imply $A \subset B$ and not $B \subset A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> 1. Why does $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B$ imply $A \subset B$ and not $B \subset A$?

When we show that $x$ is in $A$, then we show it is in $B$. So why does that imply $A\subset B$? And how do we prove this?

> 2. $A \cup B = A \cap B$ Show that A = B

I can make a Venn diagram :

[image]

But how do we prove it in words or using properties?

Comment: Can be useful to review the definition of $A \subset B$ ...

Comment: http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Implies_and_subset_relation draw a much smaller A (anything that is contained in B - but not equal to B) and find a point in B but not in A, then $B\not{\subset} A$

Comment: Although I don't like the idea, I think being formal will not help you understand in this situation, so I ask you this:

So... we know that if a thing is cat, then it is an animal. You are saying that, from this, we can imply that the set of animals is a subset of the set of cats?

Comment: I disagree with your description of the argument as "We show that $x$ is in $A$, then we show that it is in $B$." To prove the implication, we **assume** that $x\in A$, and we use this assumption to prove that $x\in B$.

Comment: I recommend considering a specific example where $A\subseteq B$ but not $B\subseteq A$; for example, let $A$ be the set of all dogs and $B$ the set of all animals.  See which of the following implications is correct: (1) "If $x$ is a dog then $x$ is an animal." (2) "If $x$ is an animal then $x$ is a dog."

Comment: Thank you everyone! can you tell me a good resource on sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

Because $A \subset B$ if every element of a is also an element of B. Note: this does not tell you whether **every** element of B is also in A. You know that some elements of B are in A, but you don't know about **all** of them, which is what's important.

Example: Let A = {0,1,2} and let B = {0,1,2,3}. You have $A \subseteq B$. $B$ is not a subset of $A$ because $3$ is in $B$, and not in $A$.

2.

Use the definitions of union and intersection. If the set of all elements of both $A$ and $B$ is also the set of all elements shared by $A$ and $B$, then $A$ and $B$ must both share all their elements. So they must contain the same elements. So they must be equal.

Comment: thank you! can you help me with a good book on sets? my text book is not very good

Comment: @TimKrul Daniel Velleman's *How to Prove It*, 2nd. edition

Answer (score 0):

1. Question is unclear
2. $n(A \cup B) = n(A \cap B) + n(A \setminus B) + n(B \setminus A$)

$A \cup B = A \cap B$ $\Rightarrow$ $A \setminus B = B \setminus A = \emptyset$

i.e. There is no element that is in A but not in B and there is no element that is in B but not in A. So, both sets are equal.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't tell us how the relation $A \subset B$ was defined to you, we can't provide an answer.
2. $A \cap B$ is contained in both $A$ and $B$. So $A \cup B = A \cap B \subset A$, and this means that $B \subset A$. Similarly, $A \cup B \subset B$, and therefore $A \subset B$. We conclude that $A=B$.

Answer (score 0):

1) So we have that (i suppose)  $ \forall x \in A \Rightarrow  x \in B $ this statement means that every element in $ A $ is also an element of $ B $, that is the precise definition of $ A \subset B $, the other implication is not valid from the hypotesis we take, that's because we don't know the relations between the elements of $B$ and $A$ .

2) For this we use the definition of Union and Intersection

> $x \in A \cup B \iff x \in A $ or $x \in B $
>
> $x \in A \cap B \iff x \in A $ and $x \in B$

So we have that if $ A \cup B = A \cap B $ every element of $A \cup B$ is both in $A$ and in $B$ so from the first statement we have the proof of the proposition.